# How to add childviewcontroller from appdelegate when fcm arrives

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification

Need to show a specific view when FCM is received.    I have managed to do this in one view controller but when the app is in some other view controller it is not showing the view. I have more than 15 pages in my app  if any method that i can add specific view from appdelegate

Comment: How did you achieve this when you are in specific view?

Comment: You can use `NSNotificationCenter` and register for notification in `AppDelegate`.

Comment: i have posted the notification details from appdeleage and added notification observer in my specific view controller

Comment: @Bogdan so i have to add observer in every view controller for catching my FCM ?

Comment: @MidhunNarayan yes, you could do it like this. Or if you have a common parent class you can implement there. Or you can save the `NavigationController` in the `AppDelegate` and push from the `AppDelegate`. It's just a thought...

Comment: @Bogdan yes i have UIviewcontroller extended common class thanks for the help

Comment: @MidhunNarayan Glad I could help you.